# C# Web API route POST always returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api2

I have a question regarding routing a POST request with ASP.NET Web API 2.

I cannot seem to call a POST function, it always returns not found 404.

```
{
   "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://....../api/CombinedPOResponse/PostCombinedPOResponse'.",
   "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'CombinedPOResponse' that matches the request."
}
```

Can someone point where my configuration is broken?
Here is the relevant part of the controller

```
namespace FormSupportService.Controllers
{
    public class CombinedPOResponseController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult PostCombinedPOResponse(string inputXml)
        {
            AddPurchaseOrderResponse response = new AddPurchaseOrderResponse();
            //...
            return Ok(response);
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

And the WebApiConfig.cs extract

```
    // UnitCodeLookup
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "CombinedPOResponseApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { inputXml = RouteParameter.Optional }
     );
```

I can reach all of the other controllers without issues, but this one is tricky.

Thank you

Edit:

I am calling the service with javascript:

```
$.ajax("/api/CombinedPOResponse/PostCombinedPOResponse",
    {
        accepts: "text/html",
        data: {inputXml: inputXml},
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'POST',
        error: error,
        success: success
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think sometimes by default, the route will omit the post part, can you try call it with just CombinedPOResponse?

Comment: Right now you are using the same name for the controller *and* action. You should probably name the `Post` action just `Post`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, in the following code

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "CombinedPOResponseApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { inputXml = RouteParameter.Optional } //this line is not necessary
 );
```

setting `inputXml` default value isn't necessary, you can omit this.

To make the request work you have to add `[FromBody]` to action parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PostCombinedPOResponse([FromBody] string inputXml)
{
    AddPurchaseOrderResponse response = new AddPurchaseOrderResponse();
    //...
    return Ok(response);
}
```

If you try this code everything will work fine except `inputXml` will always be `null`. To fix this you need to update your javascript

```
$.ajax("/api/CombinedPOResponse/PostCombinedPOResponse",
{
    accepts: "text/html",
    data: {"": inputXml}, //empty name
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    error: error,
    success: success
});
```